# PHP-Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in Mac

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I tried to search in google and the solution i found are changing the httpd.conf user from _www to my own login name then restart the apache but it didn't work.. I did it in the terminal. Another is to change the group from _www to nobody ... didn't work also.

Could anyone help me with this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Set directory permission to 777 where you are trying to make that dir.

Comment: @silentboy I did it like this.. mkdir("../user/uname/",0777);

Comment: `user/` have to be writeable

Comment: solved... the user/ folder is set to read only thats why i cant add directory... thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably isn't the httpd.conf file but the directory in which you want to create your new directory. Make sure that the user under which php is executed has the right to create a directory there. To find out which user that is (maybe `_www` as you mentioned that) you can use the `phpinfo()` command.

This is how my (default ubuntu configuration) phpinfo looks like:

> > Configuration -> apache2handler -> User/Group: www-data(33)/33

meaning you would probably want to change the owner or group of said folder to `www-data` (or whatever suits) and give the owner or group write permissions

Comment: in my httpd.conf it is written as User _www Group _www . Is it applicable?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: it didn't work .. but thanks anyways :)